# How to change what a div output with jquery

Tags: jquery

I am pulling data from a API

```
doPull('pointone', 'mode');
```

when I have the the pulled data display I am getting the a numeric value

```
<div class="container">
    <p>Mode:</p>
    <div id="mode" class="mode"></div>
</div>
```

Results in numeric values 1-3 depending on pointone value.

How do I get this to return a different value.

Example: I would like to return "Working" if pointones value is 1.

Comment: Look into `if/else` and `switch`. To use `if/else`, for instance, you could say `if (pointone === 1) return "Working"; else if (pointone === 2) return "Something else"; else ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways you could do this. I would use an array.

Based on your comments, let's say your html file is `index.html`

In `index.html` you'd want something like:

```
<script src="pull.js"></script>
<script src="convert.js"></script>
```

Adjusting the paths as needed

In `pull.js` you'd have your pull API code:

```
    // just simulating your API here
   function doPull(pointone, mode) {
     return 3;
   }
```

Then in `convert.js` you'd have:

```
   var responses = ['some text', 'some other text', 'still other text'];
   $('#mode').html(responses[doPull('pointone', 'mode')-1]);
   // mind the  "-1" bit here, this is needed because
   // array indices start at 0 and your possible values start at 1
```

---

## If `doPull()` is some sort of Ajax call, the result will not be immediately available and you will need to set it up using a callback of some sort like this:

In `index.html` you'd want something like:

```
<script src="pull.js"></script>
<script src="convert.js"></script>
```

Adjusting the paths as needed

In `pull.js` you'd have your pull API code:

```
    // just simulating your API here
   function doPull(pointone, mode) {
       $.ajax({
             url: "demo_test.txt", 
             success: function(result){
                  // when the success callback is fired, call your convert function and pass the returned value
                  myConvertFunction(result);
             }
        });
   }
```

Then in `convert.js` you'd have:

```
myConvertFunction(result){
       var responses = ['some text', 'some other text', 'still other text'];
       $('#mode').html(result-1]);
       // mind the  "-1" bit here, this is needed because
       // array indices start at 0 and your possible values start at 1 
#Here are some examples# 
}
```

### Using an array:

```js
   var responses = ['some text', 'some other text', 'still other text'];

   $('#mode').html(responses[doPull('pointone', 'mode')-1]);


    // just simulating your API here
   function doPull(pointone, mode) {
     return 3;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <p>Mode:</p>
  <div id="mode" class="mode"></div>
</div>
```

### Using if else statements:

```js
var i = doPull('pointone', 'mode');
if (i == 1) value = "some text";
else if (i == 2) value = "some ohter text";
else if (i == 3) value = "still other text";
else value = "error";
// note that brackets are optional for single line statements

$('#mode').html(value);


// just simulating your API here
function doPull(pointone, mode) {
  return 3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <p>Mode:</p>
  <div id="mode" class="mode"></div>
</div>
```

### Using a [switch statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch):

```js
switch (doPull('pointone', 'mode')) {
    case 1:
        value = "some text";
        break;
    case 2:
        value = "some ohter text";
        break;
    case 3:
        value = "still other text";
        break;
    default:
        value = "error";
        break;
}
    
$('#mode').html(value);


// just simulating your API here
function doPull(pointone, mode){
  return 3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <p>Mode:</p>
    <div id="mode" class="mode"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Again I apologize for my misuse of any terms. 

If my pulls have to be in a separate .js file how would call that data to another .js file?

Comment: @votaku No worries, we were all there once.

Comment: so let call the file that pulls all the data pull.js and I want to convert the pull data in convert.js. Sorry if that sounds stupid.

Comment: @votaku Also, if `doPull()` is some sort of Ajax call (seems likely) you'll need to use a callback> Ive adding an example of that method as well.